# Errors with Returning Values

Tags: python, return

UPDATE: So after taking some advice, I've changed how values are returned. The edits are reflected below. However, the program is now telling me that the displayRent() function is missing the 'deposit' value, even though I am returning it properly now. Any ideas?

So I'm writing this program for my programming final. It takes user input based on types of apartments and such (values 1-3, 4 to exit) and their choice of furnished or unfurnished. With these values, it finds the name, deposit, and rent. However, for some reason, my values are not being returned to the main() function where they're needed for the next function in the chain.

Sidenotes: The way this code is written is as instructed by my professor.
This program isn't finished, either. But these bits of code are giving me problems that are barring me from progress.

All help is appreciated!

```
##################################################
# This program displays possible living spaces,  #
# and gives total prices upon certain options of #
# a said space is chosen.                        #
##################################################

###############################
# Matthew Bobrowski           #
# CSC122-07 Final             #
# December 17th, 2016         #
###############################

print("""Matthew Bobrowski
CSC 122-07 Final Program
December 18th, 2016, 11:59pm""")

def main():

    print("Please choose one of the options listed. (1-4)")
    print("""
    1. Studio
    2. One-Bedroom
    3. Two-Bedroom
    4. Exit
    """)
    choiceInput, furnishedInput = getType()
    rent, deposit = determineRent(choiceInput, furnishedInput)
    displayRent(choiceInput, rent, deposit)

def getType():
    choiceInput = input("Choice: ")
    furnishedInput = input("Furnished? (Y/N): ")
    if choiceInput != 1 or choiceInput != 2 or choiceInput != 3 or choiceInput != 4:
        print("Invalid entry. Please try again.")
        choiceInput = input("Choice: ")
    if furnishedInput != 'Y' or furnishedInput != 'y' or furnishedInput != 'N' or furnishedInput != 'n':
        print("Invalid entry. Please try again.")
        furnishedInput = input("Furnished? (Y/N): ")
    return choiceInput, furnishedInput

def determineRent(choiceInput, furnishedInput):
    rent = 0
    deposit = 0

    if choiceInput == 1:
        if furnishedInput == 'Y' or furnishedInput == 'y':
            rent = 750
            deposit = 400
        elif furnishedInput == 'N' or furnishedInput == 'n':
            rent = 600
            deposit = 400
    elif choiceInput == 2:
        if furnishedInput == 'Y' or furnishedInput == 'y':
            rent = 900
            deposit = 500
        elif furnishedInput == 'N' or furnishedInput == 'n':
            rent = 750
            deposit = 500
    elif choiceInput == 3:
        if furnishedInput == 'Y' or furnishedInput == 'y':
            rent = 1025
            deposit = 600
        elif furnishedInput == 'N' or furnishedInput == 'n':
            rent = 925
            deposit = 600
    elif choiceInput == 4:
        quit
    return rent, deposit

def displayRent(choiceInput, furnishedInput, rent, deposit):
    if choiceInput == 1:
        if furnishedInput == 'y' or furnishedInput == 'Y':
            print("""
            TYPE: STUDIO - FURNISHED
            DEPOSIT: $""" + str(deposit) + """
            RENT: $""" + str(rent))
        else:
            print("""
            TYPE: STUDIO - UNFURNISHED
            DEPOSIT: $""" + str(deposit) + """
            RENT: $""" + str(rent))
    return


main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getType()` is returning values, yes? So, capture them.

```
choiceInput, furnishedInput = getType() # Get the values
determineRent(choiceInput, furnishedInput) # Same issue here...
```

---

Second problem: `input()` returns a string. You have to cast it

```
choiceInput = int(input("Choice: "))
```

---

And tip: Your if statements can be simplified by lowercasing the values

```
if furnishedInput.lower() == 'y':
```

Comment: When I tried doing that, it recalled the inputs twice each, then failed.

Comment: Probably you are comparing strings and ints

Comment: Actually, never mind. Something was incorrect the previous iteration; it passes now. Thank you so much!

Comment: New errors have risen... could use your help once again.

Comment: Discovered the issue, sorry for the consistent reply spam, haha. I forgot to edit the call in main() to include furnishedInput.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if you have a function and you return something, you need to store the returned result:

```
def example():
     return "hello world"
store = example()
print example
```

if you want to compare if none of your option is chosen, use `and`:

```
if choiceInput != 1 and choiceInput != 2 and choiceInput != 3 and choiceInput != 4:
```

or in a slightly more python way:

```
if choiceInput not in (1,2,3,4):
```

also, consider to use a loop, the if condition condition will only catch one faulty input, what if the user enters 2 faulty entries?

Comment: Forgot to add the fact that my program had checks for invalid inputs, but I removed them during debugging. I had it reload the input each false input until an accepted one was given. :)